# How to insert an "index.php" into every url using .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

Example: My Site gets called like that:

```
www.example.com/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2
```

Now, .htaccess needs to rewrite this URL into:

```
www.example.com/index.php/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2
```

But the problem is: In case of an **img**, **css** or **js** directory, no redirection should happen.

How can I achieve this? I only know the mod-rewrite engine is my friend here.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Khal Weir's answer, the resulting rule should be something like :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^(/css/|/js/|/images/|/robots.txt)
RewriteRule . /index.php/ [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you filter it as the other recommended it or you filter for files existing on the hard drive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php/ [L]
```

These days most CMS systems filter it like this.

Comment: +1 This is actually a "better" way to do it than what I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|images|robots\.txt)
```